# Pick the second last element of the list

Tags: haskell

After some time I've decied to back to learning some functional programming. I've decided to pick Haskell this time, because of its features and .. syntax.

At the moment I am doing some exercises and I am stuck. I want to write a function that picks second last element from the list, i.e. given [1,2,3,4] it would 3.

Here's my function.

```
lastButOne xs 
    | null xs = xs 
    | length xs == 1 = xs 
    | length xs == 2 = lastButOne head xs
    | otherwise = lastButOne tail xs
```

Unfortunately it yields some errors.

```
Couldn't match expected type `[a]' with actual type `[a1] -> [a1]'
Relevant bindings include
  xs :: [a] (bound at lastButOne.hs:1:12)
  lastButOne :: [a] -> [a] (bound at lastButOne.hs:1:1)
Probable cause: `tail' is applied to too few arguments
In the first argument of `lastButOne', namely `tail'
In the expression: lastButOne tail xs
```

I've tried with some parthness, like (head xs) and (tail xs), but it doesn't help.

```
   Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
   Expected type: [[a]]
     Actual type: [a]
   Relevant bindings include
     xs :: [a] (bound at lastButOne.hs:1:12)
     lastButOne :: [a] -> [a] (bound at lastButOne.hs:1:1)
   In the first argument of `head', namely `xs'
   In the first argument of `lastButOne', namely `(head xs)'
```

**Follow-up**:
Or should I write Follow-up's. Well, my orginal idea was to write a function that yields head element if list length is one. So given the Lee's explanation it's easy to come up with the following:

```
lastPattern :: [a] -> Maybe a
lastPattern [] = Nothing
lastPattern [x] = Just x
lastPattern [x,_] = Just x
lastPattern (_:xs) = lastPattern xs
```

Ane here's the first question. *What is the pattern for both conditions [x] and [x,_]*?

Next thing I wanted to do is to write the same function with the reverse (as pointed out by Paul Johnson). I quickly came up with `head (tail (reverse [1,2,3,4]))` which seemed to work fine in the REPL. But when I started some coding I end up with

```
 lastRev :: [a] -> a
lastRev xs 
    | null xs = error "empty list"
    | length xs == 1 = error "too short"
    | otherwise = head (tail (reverse xs))
```

since the head function is `head :: [a] -> a` . The above function is a little mess for my taste, so to say. *Is there any way I could make it to be `:: [a] -> Maybe a` ?* That's the second question.

Last but not least - the third question. *Which function is better in terms of performance? How can I measure it in Haskell?*

Comment: Any reason you can't use "reverse"?

Comment: No particular reason. As I wrote, I am just learning and I wanted to implement this "my" way, not the "best" or the "correct" way. I just want to better understand the language. Perhaps I will tackle this problem with the reverse function within a few minutes. So thank you for pointing this out. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(head xs)` returns an `a` and you're trying to pass it to `lastButOne` which requires a `[a]` argument. You could just return `head xs` directly in this case. You also have a problem with the first two cases since they return a list, while an element is required. Since there is no such element in this cases you could return an error:

```
lastButOne :: [a] -> a
lastButOne xs 
    | null xs = error "empty list"
    | length xs == 1 = error "list too short"
    | length xs == 2 = head xs
    | otherwise = lastButOne (tail xs)
```

are more functional solution would be to encode the partiality in the function type and return a `Maybe a` so you can return `Nothing` if the input list is too short:

```
lastButOne :: [a] -> Maybe a
lastButOne xs 
    | null xs = Nothing
    | length xs == 1 = Nothing
    | length xs == 2 = Just (head xs)
    | otherwise = lastButOne (tail xs)
```

finally, a better solution would be to use pattern matching instead of guarding on the length:

```
lastButOne :: [a] -> Maybe a
lastButOne [] = Nothing
lastButOne [_] = Nothing
lastButOne [x,_] = Just x
lastButOne (_:xs) = lastButOne xs
```

Comment: what's wrong with doing `lst !! (length lst - 2)` as the 3rd case? saves you recursion

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I haven't read about the pattern matching yet, that's why I am using guards.

Comment: @ElectricCoffee, it's slower and also less obviously total than the pattern matching version.

Comment: `xs !! (length xs - 2)` could be more efficient if `!!` was random-access. Haskell's standard `[]` data type denotes a recursive access-O(n) linked-list data structure. `length` is Θ(n). Both `!!` and `length` are defined using recursion. Don't avoid recursion in Haskell; learn when and how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple errors here.

First, call syntax binds to the left, which means that `lastButOne head xs` means "call `lastButOne` with two arguments, `head` and `xs`", instead of the "call `lastButOne` with the result of calling `head` with `xs`".

Second, your function returns a list, even though your description says it should return a single element.

Third, the call `lastButOne (head xs)` is also a type error, since `head` returns a single element, but `lastButOne` expects a list. I believe you meant to simply write `head xs` here.

But then you get to the fourth error, which is that the first two branches of your function actually return the entire list, which they can't if you want to return a single element.

You also need to think about what the function *should* return when it isn't at least two elements long. Should it crash, as `head` does? Or should you actually change the result type to `Maybe a` and return `Nothing`?

Answer (score 0):

I am newbie to Haskell, however this is solution I did:

```
lastButOne xs = if null xs || length xs == 1
            then []
            else
                if length xs == 2
                then head xs
                else lastButOne (tail xs)
```

Comment: Do you understand why this is very slow?

Comment: Hint: you call `length`.